# How does negative character class subtraction work in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, f#

According to the .Net documentation on Regex, one can use [Character Class Subtractions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#character-class-subtraction-base_group---excluded_group), in the form of:

> [base_group - [excluded_group]]

Both `base_group` and `excluded_group` can be [positive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#positive-character-group--) and [negative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#NegativeGroup) character groups.

However, see the following #fsharp code:

```
let pattern = "([^A-F-[C-D]])"

"ABCDEFG".ToCharArray()
|>  Array.iter(fun s -> printfn "%c - %b" s ((Regex.Match (string(s), pattern)).Success))
```

With the following output:

```
A - false
B - false
C - false
D - false
E - false
F - false
G - true
```

I was expecting `true` on "C" and "D".

The following pattern gives the same result: "([^A-F-[CD]])" (note I changed character range [C-D] into characterset [CD])

Am I doing this the right way?

I did a few extra tests, and this code:

```
let pattern = "([^A-F-[^KL]])"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".ToCharArray()
|>  Array.iter(fun s -> printfn "%c - %b" s ((Regex.Match (string(s), pattern)).Success))
```

Gives this result:

```
A - false
B - false
C - false
D - false
E - false
F - false
G - false
H - false
I - false
J - false
K - true
L - true
M - false
N - false
O - false
P - false
```

Which suggests that I might gotten the interpretation incorrect. [The spec says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#character-class-subtraction-base_group---excluded_group):

> Character class subtraction yields a set of characters that is the
> result of excluding the characters in one character class from another
> character class.

So the root of confusion might be that I expected the subtraction operation to work during the **construction** of the character class, while it works on character class **constructs**.

With this interpretation, if I have a pattern like this: [^A-F-[C-D]]
This does *not* mean that "C-D" should be subtracted from "A-F".
It means that we match true on any character except "A-F" and we subtract a match on "C-D" - for which it already did not match. That's why it appears ineffective.

So `[^A-F]` is character class in its own right, it's atomic and a subtraction operation works on the resulting set of characters.

The second pattern demonstrates this interpretation even better: [^A-F-[^KL]]
Read like this. We match true for anything except "A-F" and we subtract matches on anything except "KL". Simple set-subtraction and this result in "KL".

Comment: So, the set of "not A thru F" doesn't contain C or D, so removing C and D from it would be a non op..

Comment: ..but I just realized you're probably looking at it as "not (A to F minus C to D)" rather than "(everything except A to F) minus (C to D)"

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting true on "C" and "D".

Why? You defined a set of `[CD]` to be subtracted out or ignored.^1

I get the confusion in the wordy document referenced, frankly, it instead be called this:

**Set Subtraction Negation Pattern**

Which may better imparts that one is **negating** an existing pattern with a **subset** *pattern* to achieve a finer result.

---

A better example is this

```
var test = "1234567890";
var pattern = @"[\d-[57]]";
```

Which would match any number except 5 or 7. In the `[ ]` set, it contains a `\d` any digit, then the substraction set, says skip these items in this sub set of `5` and `7` *Not six, we did not combine them with a `-` in our set*.

The pattern I offered above is a character subtraction pattern `[\d-[57]]` which works on all digits except for 5 and 7.  This comes in handy when one has a character class that nearly meets the needs; except that it contains one or a few characters that one **wishes to exclude**.

---

^1 Attaching the `-` as `C-D` (C through D) does nothing because there are no characters between the C and D; hence it is a set of two characters `CD` and **not a series**.